# How to use React Redux store in component that modifies and renders the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

In `Text` component, I want to get `text_data` from DB once and save it to the Redux store.

```js
export default function Text() {

  const [document, setDocument] = useState([]);
  setDocument(useSelector(currentState))

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/api/texts/${docId}`).then((response) => {
      dispatch(currentState(response.data));
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="Text">
        {document.text && document.text.map((text, index) => (
          <div onClick={() => {dispatch(changeColor(index))}}>
            {text.word}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then I'd like to get the `text_data` **from Redux store** probably in the same component

```
  setDocument(useSelector(currentState))
```

But it causes infinite rerender.

Moreover, I'd like to modify the `text_data` with clicks so that `Text` component will show text in different colors after click. For that, I'd like to modify Redux state and rerender `Text` component.

`text_data` has a structure `{word: color, second_word: color, ...}`

How to use Redux for that? Is it possible, is my thinking correct that the redux state should be the only one thing that should change?

EDIT: Code snippet added. I am working on this so my code snippet doesn't work.

Comment: Hi David! I don't think the code snippets are enough to understand the problem. Could you post more code from the component where you are trying to use this?

Comment: @NicolásLonghi I added some code, maybe it's more informative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not understand [react-redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-hooks-in-a-react-redux-app) correctly. These two lines does not make sense. I don't know what your `currentState` variable should be in your snippet. But the usage is definitely wrong.

```js
setDocument(useSelector(currentState))
dispatch(currentState(response.data));
```

I don't know what your redux store looks like. In next snippets I will assume that it is something like this.

```js
// redux store structure
{
  texts: {document: {}, coloredWords: {}}
}

// fetched document will have structure something like this (array of words)
{text: []}
```

Your (texts) reducer should modified the redux store like this (written just schematically)

```js
// ...

// storing fetched document
case 'SET_DOCUMENT': {
  const document = action.payload
  return {...state, document: document}
}

// storing color for word at particular index
case 'CHANGE_COLOR': {
  const {index, color} = action.payload
  return {...state, coloredWords: {...state.coloredWords, [index]: color}}
}

// ...
```

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { setDocument, changeColor } from 'path_to_file_with_action_creators'

export default function Text() {  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  // get fetched document from your redux store (it will be an empty object in the first render, while fetch in the useEffect hook is called after the first render)
  const document = useSelector(state => state.texts.document))
  // get colors for document words (they were saved in redux store by your onClick handler, see bellow)
  const coloredWords = useSelector(state => state.texts.coloredWords))

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch document
    axios.get(`/api/texts/${docId}`).then((response) => {
      // store fetched document in your redux store
      dispatch(setDocument(response.data));
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="Text">
        {document && document.text && document.text.map((text, index) => (
          <div
            style={{color: coloredWords[index] ? coloredWords[index] : 'black' }}
            onClick={() => {
              // store color for word at particular index in redux store
              dispatch(changeColor({index: index, color: 'red'}))
            }}
          >
            {text.word}
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello @lavor. Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm still trying to understand it. In my case the Text() component renders the initial document state, then the document is updated with the data fetched with axios in redux but it is not rerendering the component with the new, fetched data

Comment: Ok I may not be right. It looks like your solution is correct and helps me. I need to verify it still. Nevertheless thank you for your engagement. I will confirm whether it works